# How to show that $E$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and suppose that it has the following property

> Every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.

I want to show that $E$ is closed.

Efforts:

Idea: I know that idea is to first assume on the contrary that set is not closed. Then find an infinite subset which does not have not a limit point in $E$

Let us assume that $E$ is not closed.(Recall the definition that a set is closed iff it contain all its limit point) So we have a limit point say $x_0$ of $E$ which does not belong to $E$.

Now as $x_0$ is a limit point every nbd of $x_0$ contains a point of $E$ other than $x_0$. In particular take $\delta=1/n$ and choose $x_n$ such that $|x_n-x_0|<1/n$

Let us collect all these points $\{x_n\}$. I have an intutive idea that this is an example of an infinite set of $E$ which does not have the limit in $E$

I am not able to write the ideas rigorously. I would be thankful if somebody can show me the right path.

Comment: What is your definition of "closed"?

Comment: The sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x_0$. Show that $\{x_n:n\ge1\}$ has only one limit point, viz., $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is fine. Note that $x_0=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. But in a metric space a seuence cannot have more than one limit. So, $x_0$ is the *only* limit of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. But if $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ had another limit point $y\in E$, then $y$ would be the limit of a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Now, note that any such subsequence converges to $x_0$ too.

Comment: I can not see why this set is always infinite. How can I properly argue that set is infinite. This is what I think, suppose that this set was finite then we would have a fix value(which is positive) for infinite many values of $x_n$ but then what?

Comment: The set of the distances of $x_n$ to $x_0$ is infinite. Therefore,  the set of all $x_n$'s is infinite too.

Answer (score 1):

By your definition of the sequence $(x_{n})$ one can easily see that $(x_{n})$ converges to $x_{0}$ and thus $x_{0}$ is its only limit point which does not lie in $E$.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the $x_n$ are distinct, define $x_n\in B(x_0,\frac1n)\setminus \{x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}\}$.  Note that points are closed in a metric space,  so taking finitely many points out leaves you with an open set.